I am trying to implement downdrop menus from Bootstrap 5
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/dropdownmenus/contenido/5.company.html"   id="navbarDropdownCompany" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">COMPANY</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropstart">
    
            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"       href="/dropdownmenus/contenido/5.1.overview.html"  id="navbarDropdownOverview" role="button" 
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> OVERVIEW </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >    
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/dropdownmenus/contenido/5.1.1.revenue.html">REVENUE</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/dropdownmenus/contenido/5.1.2.subscribers.html">SUBSCRIBERS</a>
                  </LI       
                </ul>
              </li>

I am trying to implement a submenu in a dropdown in Bootstrap5, it isn't working properly after a few days trying. Does anyone know where my code is wrong?
About the image,
The subdropdown isn't working when I put my pointer over it or I click on it
I tried the previous code
This is how it looks now

Try to add "show" to
<ul class="dropdown-menu" > 
like this
<ul class="dropdown-menu show" > 

I tried and this is what happens  it first appears like this
And after I click the button again it looks like this
